# Faster Excel Upload Using Apache POI

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-poi, jxl

I have a routine process like monthly uploading an Excel file to db. Excel file consists of 2 sheets and like 4320 lines and too much columns. The application i use is an old desktop system coded using Java and DAO-DTO structures. I need to speed up the process. Is there a way for POI to speed it up, or would you just suggest me optimize your code, refactor it etc.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're asking whether POI is faster than Jxl, the answer in my experience is no, by several orders of magnitude. If there are zillions of columns it's possible that you're network-bound rather than Excel-bound.

Comment: Where is all the time going? If you run it through a profiler, what does that show?